# sending csv line with email

Tags: c#, csv, filereader

I want to find a date on csv file I want to send this line as an email for example 
`adam smit;1.12.2014` im using this code but body always empty I wonder what causes that?
thanks for help

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.csv");    
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{

    int i = 0;
    string[] words = line.Split(";"[0]);
    if (words[i] == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) 
    {
         mail.Body = line;
    }   
    i++;
    counter++;                                      
}
```

Comment: date is in `words[1]`. Also your DateTime format should be `"d.MM.yyyy"` (or maybe `"d.M.yyyy"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Variable `i` is always 0. And you should append your line to the `mail.body` and not overwrite the whole body.

Try this:

```
var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.csv");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(';');
    DateTime dt;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(words[1], new CultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) 
        && dt.Date == DateTime.Today)
    {
        mail.Body += line + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable declaration [i] should precede the control loop, not fall within it.

Answer (score -1):

words[i] gives you always 0 item, as you don't do any loop inside. so instead of:

```
if (words[i] == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) 
{
```

use

```
if (words[1] == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) 
{
```

you don't need i variable and i++ increment

Comment: `words[i] gives you a whole line`. Wrong.